# Keep search interface open

Tags: android, search

Is there a way to keep the search (widget or dialog) open even if the user clicks on the screen? I've seen many Google apps doing this (Keep, GMail, Youtube...) but not so many apps from external developers...

I have my search edit text visible on the ActionBar but as soon as I tap somewhere else on the screen, it is dismissed. I only want it dismissed if the user clicks on the action bar icon or presses the back key.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Intercept the touch event on the container view.
2. Check if the SearchView is expanded.
   If it is do nothing

Other idea, is cutting the `SearchView` being collapsed whenever the container sends touch event signals down to the view tree if it is already expanded. Or make sure it does not collapse when the SearchView looses the focus. Make sure you properly collapsed, when back key is pressed.
These are just ideas.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I think #1 won't work because I want to be able to interact with the activity behind, but anyway I will give it a try. Thanks!